# Error creating partition with curl on Marklogic

Tags: curl, marklogic

I tried using this command on windows trying to connect to Marklogic server

```
curl --anyauth --user admin:password -X POST \
-d@"C:\marklogic\partition.xml" \
-H 'Content-type: application/xml' \
"http://www.myserver:8019/manage/v2/databases/movie/partitions"
```

But I am getting :

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application
```

My http server is running on `localhost:8019` and my database name is movie. The file `partition.xml` contains partition information.

Can somebody help me whether /manage/v2/databases/movie is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicates you're having a problem with curl.

The lack of a space between `-d` and `@` may be throwing off the interpreter.

EDIT: also, if your server is `localhost` then you may want to put that in the url, `localhost:8019` instead of `www.myserver:8019`.

Comment: As Laurel points out, www.myserver is probably not a valid hostname.

Answer (score 0):

It could depend on how you execute above command. If running from inside a script, you might need to take extra measures to escape quotes, or wrap them in extra ones. The error messages seems to indicate that curl is not seeing the single quotes value behind -H as one value, but as two. Try replacing those single quotes with double ones, or wrap the argument in extra double quotes..

HTH!